# Host based firewall in NAT environments

Tags: networking, firewall, nat

Hi getting straight to the point. I am currently working on the architecture of a Host based firewall.

My question/pain point is what happens to these(Host Based Firewalls) when LAN-LAN NAT rules are enabled on physical routers. So if a **LAN1 : Machine A** wants to contact **LAN2 : Machine B** it will go via a router **R1** and this router with ***SNAT*** the IP of the *incoming packet* from **Machine A** therefore, **Machine B** will never know the IP of Machine A which further implies that it wont be able to create any IP based rules for traffic coming from Machine A.

Is there a solution to this problem? Is my understanding of NAT environment correct?

**=====THE PROBLEM=====**

I have two machines sending there network activity logs to a central server, based on these logs I create firewall policies and sync them to endpoints. So the log from **Machine A** for the packet going from **Machine A** to **Machine B** will have **Machine A's** local IP but when it is received at **Machine B** it will have the **Router's IP**. Therefore, the logs that I receive for this connection from A and B will never be justified and my policies will not work.

I am looking for a solution/workaround for this scenario where i can either map the Routers IP to the original source IP or know at Machine A itself that this particular outgoing packet will get SNAT to Router's IP.

Comment: I can say, yes you got it, but beware of the [XY](http://xyproblem.info/) [problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Do you have a concrete existing problem, to describe, you want to address? This could help find answers, even using alternate methods.

Comment: Fair enough , I have edited the question please check it now.

Comment: Ok, the easiest would of course be there is no NAT done. Else this would require R1 sends logs of NAT alterations it did to get the lost information available. I don't suppose this can be an answer, so I'll leave it to other people having better ideas.

Comment: Okay thanks , what if I use the MAC address to obtain the original IP address?

Comment: You're not very specific. You see the router's MAC address